# A global variable accesible in all files codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I declare a variable or global variable which is accessible in all files whether controller,model,view and set a value for it when  call it from the current file??

Comment: Yes you can define that thing in application/config/constant.php

Comment: constant != variable

Comment: Create hook and set it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a core controller (MY_Controller) and initiate all your variables there and have you controllers extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller